# Space in Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I'm fairly new to batches. Starting to learn the basics but already run into a problem.

So my Code looks something like this:

```
findstr /i /m Findthisstring C:\Users\XY\Desktop\Start\*.* > test.lst
for /f %%I in (C:\Users\XY\Desktop\test.lst) do @move %%I C:\Users\XY\Desktop\Target\

pause
```

The Problem here is, that I also receive Files with spaces. For Example "File with Spacer.pdf". 
I already tried to use quotation marks. But these didnt work out for me.

Maybe you can give me a hint how to solve this one.

Thanks!

Edit:

Tried to use the quotation marks direct at the file name ("* ".*).

```
findstr /i /m Findthisstring C:\Users\XY\Desktop\Start\"*".* > test.lst
for /f %%I in (C:\Users\XY\Desktop\test.lst) do @move %%I C:\Users\XY\Desktop\Target\

pause
```

And I tried to use it for the whole path ("C:\Users\XY\Desktop\Start*.*")

```
findstr /i /m Findthisstring "C:\Users\XY\Desktop\Start\*.*" > test.lst
for /f %%I in (C:\Users\XY\Desktop\test.lst) do @move %%I C:\Users\XY\Desktop\Target\

pause
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the **[edit]** link below it) and show us the code where you used double quotes (`"`)

Comment: Double quotes enclose things with spaces.

Comment: Can you tell me, what do you mean with this @Mark?

Comment: `C:\Users\XY\Desktop\test.lst` or `%%I` must be enclosed in quotes. All parameters containing spaces must be quoted.

Comment: Now the batch is moving the .lst file to my destination Folder. The Files in the "Start" Folder arent moving.

Comment: Please don't put the answer into the question. Add an answer instead.

Comment: You don't really need to output to a text file then read that file, you can do it all within the same loop: `@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%I In ('%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /IMP "FindThisString" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Start\*" 2^>NUL')Do @Move /Y "%%I" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Target"`.

Comment: *Never* put quotes around partial path elements, anyways quote *whole* paths! THen take a look at the *option string* of [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), which features `usebackq`, `skip`, `delims`, `eol` and `tokens`; I'm sure you'll find a way to avoid strings to be split at whitespaces (hint: type `for /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the output help text)…

Comment: Thanks for the advices. Will look into it tomorrow again.
@Stephan im still new to stackoverflow, ill try to figure out how to put my final result as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you've seemingly ignored some of the advice provided in the comments, here's my comment again as an answer instead.

You don't really need to output to a text file then read that file, *(and then optionally delete that file)*, you can do it all within the same loop:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%I In (
    '%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /IMP "FindThisString" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Start\*" 2^>NUL'
) Do @Move /Y "%%I" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Target"
```

*Depending upon your `FindThisString` you may wish to change the options to `/IMPC:"FindThisString"` or `/LIMP "FindThisString"`*

Answer (score -1):

So i managed to get it working with the "DELIMS=" command. Also thanks @mark for the Hint with the Quoted "%%I".

My final Code:

```
findstr /i /m Findthisstring C:\Users\XY\Desktop\Start\"*".* > test.lst
for /f "DELIMS=" %%I in (C:\Users\XY\Desktop\test.lst) do @move "%%I" C:\Users\XY\Desktop\Target\

pause
```